# python: default settings for plt.pyplot.boxplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

```
>>>import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>>data = [1,2,3,4,5]                # toy data
>>>boxplot = plt.boxplot(data)
```

returns a boxplot object of type dict, whose keys are:

```
>>>boxplot.keys()
['medians', 'fliers', 'whiskers', 'boxes', 'caps']
```

I want to know how to query the default settings that matplotlib uses to generate these boxplot properties. Google hasn't helped much.

For example, how do I query the settings for which the 'boxes' property of the boxplots are generated? are they the 25th and 75th percentiles?

Comment: Did you have a look at print plt.boxplot.__doc__? At least for the  whiskers it seem to be the 25th and 75th percentiles:    *whis* : [ default 1.5 ]
    Defines the length of the whiskers as a function of the inner
    quartile range.  They extend to the most extreme data point
    within ( ``whis*(75%-25%)`` ) data range.

Comment: ah that was quite useful thanks

Comment: This question is kind of unclear to me. Do you mean that the docs did not satisfy you? If so, can you list specific questions instead of "query the default settings" which isn't very clear? My answer right now is "If google, the docs, or SO hadn't helped so far - look into the code", and I don't think that'll satisfy you although it exactly answers the question asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just get the information you need by calling `print(plt.boxplot.__doc__)`:

Here is a relevant excerpt from it (the whole thing is really long):

```
whis : float, sequence (default = 1.5) or string
        As a float, determines the reach of the whiskers past the first
        and third quartiles (e.g., Q3 + whis*IQR, IQR = interquartile
        range, Q3-Q1). Beyond the whiskers, data are considered outliers
        and are plotted as individual points. Set this to an unreasonably
        high value to force the whiskers to show the min and max values.
        Alternatively, set this to an ascending sequence of percentile
        (e.g., [5, 95]) to set the whiskers at specific percentiles of
        the data. Finally, *whis* can be the string 'range' to force the
        whiskers to the min and max of the data. In the edge case that
        the 25th and 75th percentiles are equivalent, *whis* will be
        automatically set to 'range'.
```

So yes, it is the 25th and 75th percentiles as the default is 1.5 relative to the median.